# Memory error even though RAM is free

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dbf

I am merging files together in 4 folders.  Within those 4 folders I am merging 80 `.dbf` files together each of which is 35 megabytes.  I am using the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5

list1=[]   
folders=r'F:\dbf_tables'
out=r'F:\merged'
if not os.path.isdir(out):
    os.mkdir(out)
for folder in os.listdir(folders):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(out,folder)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(out,folder))
    for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(folders,folder)):
         if '.xml' not in f:
            if '.cpg' not in f:
                 table=Dbf5(os.path.join(folders,folder,f))
                 df=table.to_dataframe()
                 list1.append(df)
                 dfs = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['POINTID'],how='outer',),list1)
                 dfs.to_csv(os.path.join(out,folder,'combined.csv'), index=False)
```

almost immediately after running the code I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-77eb6fd0cda7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/python codes/prelim_codes/raster_to_point.py', wdir='F:/python codes/prelim_codes')

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda_64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda_64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "F:/python codes/prelim_codes/raster_to_point.py", line 66, in <module>
    dfs = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['POINTID'],how='outer',),list1)

  File "F:/python codes/prelim_codes/raster_to_point.py", line 66, in <lambda>
    dfs = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['POINTID'],how='outer',),list1)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 217, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 353, in _get_join_info
    sort=self.sort, how=self.how)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 559, in _get_join_indexers
    return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)

  File "pandas\src\join.pyx", line 160, in pandas.algos.full_outer_join (pandas\algos.c:61256)

MemoryError
```

but only 30% of my memory is being used, which is pretty much the baseline.

EDIT:

I picked out only 2 files and tried the merge using:

```
merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['POINTID'], how='outer')
```

and still get a memory error, something weird is going on.

When I run the same thing in 32-bit Anaconda I get `ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`

EDIT:

The entire problem stemmed from the solution give here:
[Value Error: negative dimensions are not allowed when merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130690/value-error-negative-dimensions-are-not-allowed-when-merging)

Comment: Try using your last two rows out from both `for` loops. At your above code, in the last iteration you join your first dataset as many times as the number of files you have...

Comment: Sorry but still rather new to python, by 'out' do you mean the last two lines should be lined up with my first `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED** based on comment:

Try this (it's enough to use only one `if` statement with logical `and` conditions):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5

folders = r'F:\dbf_tables'
out = r'F:\merged'

if not os.path.isdir(out):
    os.mkdir(out)

for folder in os.listdir(folders):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(out, folder)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(out, folder))

    # Initialize empty dataframe by folders
    dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['POINTID'])

    for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(folders, folder)):
         if ('.xml' not in f) and ('.cpg' not in f):
             table = Dbf5(os.path.join(folders, folder, f))
             df = table.to_dataframe()

             # Merge actual dataframe to result dataframe
             dfs = dfs.merge(df, on=['POINTID'], how='outer')

    # Save results by folder
    dfs.to_csv(os.path.join(out, folder, 'combined.csv'), index=False)
```

Comment: I'm curious why the initial case resulted in a memory error and the answer does not?

Comment: I think they explained in a comment to the original post, It makes it join as many times as number of files, rather than just once per folder

Comment: actually, the memory error still came up, it just took one hour to do so, but this time my ram was actually full.

Comment: actually this isn't the solution, I reduced my input files to only 10 and I still get the memory error which shouldn't happen with so few files

Comment: I actually do want the last two lines in the loop, I want 4 files called `combined.csv` as the output.  One for each folder.  The entire problem stemmed from another issue entirely which I posted above.

Comment: OK. I placed `dfs` initialization and `to_csv()` into "folder loop"