# Value Error: negative dimensions are not allowed when merging

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging 2 dataframes together.  They are originally `.csv` files which are only 7 megabytes each (2 columns and 290,000 rows).  I am merging like this:

```
merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['POINTID'], how='outer')
```

and in 32-bit Anaconda I get:

`ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`

but on 64-bit Anaconda I get a memory error.

I have 12 gigabytes of RAM and only 30% of it is being used so it should not be a memory issue. I tried on another computer and get the same issue.

Comment: Can you try it on a sample? `pd.merge(df1[:100], df2[:100], on=['POINTID'], how='outer')` with 'outer' I wouldn't be so sure about the memory.

Comment: that does work, but I have joined larger files together than this using outer and had no problem.

Comment: Are the results as expected? Sometimes while merging you may have an alignment problem which introduces many NaNs. That's why I said it might be memory problem.

Comment: Yes they look as expected, there are NaN's in there, but there should be.  It is not overwhelmed with them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a 32-bit machine, the default NumPy integer dtype is `int32`.
On a 64-bit machine, the default NumPy integer dtype is `int64`.

The largest integers representable by an `int32` and `int64` are:

```
In [88]: np.iinfo('int32').max
Out[88]: 2147483647

In [87]: np.iinfo('int64').max
Out[87]: 9223372036854775807
```

So the integer index created by `pd.merge` will support a maximum of `2147483647 = 2**31-1` rows on a 32-bit machine, and `9223372036854775807 = 2**63-1` rows on a 64-bit machine.

In theory, two  290000 row DataFrames merged with an `outer` join may have as many as `290000**2 = 84100000000` rows. Since

```
In [89]: 290000**2 > np.iinfo('int32').max
Out[89]: True
```

the 32-bit machine may not be able to generate an integer index big enough to index the merged result.

And although the 64-bit machine can in theory generate an integer index big enough to accommodate the result, you may not have enough memory to build a 84 billion-row DataFrame.

Now, of course, the merged DataFrame may have fewer than 84 billion rows (the exact number depends on how many duplicate values appear in `df1['POINTID']` and  `df2['POINTID']`) but the above back-of-the envelope calculation shows that the behavior you are seeing is consistent with having a lot of duplicates.

---

PS. You can get negative values when adding or multiplying positive integers in NumPy arrays if there is arithmetic overflow:

```
In [92]: np.int32(290000)*np.int32(290000)
Out[92]: -1799345920
```

My guess is that this is the reason for the exception:

```
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Comment: So I set it up so I have two dataframes, each with 1486970 rows and use a `left` merge and the same memory error comes up

Comment: `1486970 > 290000`, and a `left` merge can also result in `N**2` number of rows. So everything written above also applies to this case.