# Why does pandas version 25.3's groupby and agg no longer work?

Tags: python, pandas

I transferred a script from one work computer to another.  The first runs pandas 24.2 and the following script that grouped and aggregated data worked.

```
df_feature_set = df_wrangled.groupby(['atfault_model2', 'majorvio_model2', 'BIlmt_model2', 'minorvio_model2'
                                      , 'Vintiles', 'multi_policy_count_model','marital_statusXage2', 'credit_buckets'
                                      , 'class_model2', 'unit_drv_exp_model2', 'unit_value_model2'
                                      , 'rating_class_code_model2', 'Right_State', 'eff_year', 'yrs_owned_model2'
                                      , 'unitnum_model2', 'count_flag', 'current_uw_model']
                                    ).agg({'bi_eu': 'sum','bi_earned': 'sum', 'bi_cnt': 'sum', 'bi_incrd': 'sum'
                                           , 'um_cnt': 'sum', 'um_earned': 'sum', 'um_incrd': 'sum'}
                                         ).reset_index()
```

The computer I transferred to runs pandas 25.3 and I get the following error:

`ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`

I went to the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) and followed the instructions to group by first, then take that object and aggregate but I'm still getting the error.  Is there something I'm missing in the update?

Comment: Did you see that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130690/value-error-negative-dimensions-are-not-allowed-when-merging

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure that applies.  I did install the 24.2 version and it worked fine.